# get line number within a eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm looking for the right extension point for my plugin to access the cursor position in the editor. The aim is to provide additional information to the current code line in a plugin view.
I sure it is possible, since the Outline view for example highlights the current function which I'm within.
thx

Comment: maybe: getCursorPosition, the String may contain the rigth information, how do i get a handle to the current Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textSelection.getOffset()` from the pattern you've found and then use the `org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument` interface to extract text from the document to do whatever analysis you want.

```
ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor)editor;
IDocumentProvider dp = editor.getDocumentProvider();
IDocument doc = dp.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
```

`IDocument` has methods to convert back and forth between character offsets and lines.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does what I want

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;        

IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
if(editor instanceof ITextEditor){
    ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = ((ITextEditor)editor).getSelectionProvider();
    ISelection selection = selectionProvider.getSelection();
    if (selection instanceof ITextSelection) {
        ITextSelection textSelection = (ITextSelection)selection;
        System.out.println("startline:"+textSelection.getStartLine());
    }
}
```