# Coloring Rows of AnnotationRulerColumn of VerticalRuler in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I’m trying to change the background color of an AnnotationRulerColumn of the VerticalRuler in Eclipse. Until now I’m only able to change the color of the whole Column respectively the area after I changed the bounds.  Is there a way to partition the Colum into rows to represent the source code lines?

```
Color co = new Color(display,2,3,2);
Color co2 = new Color(display,2,3,255);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,25,200);
column1.getControl().setBounds(rect);
column1.getControl().setBackground(co);
column2.getControl().setBackground(co2);
```

[image]

related topics:

[Eclipse editor: show markers on custom column of vertical ruler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082933/eclipse-marker-on-diffrent-column)

[creating VerticalRuler and add Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992863/creating-verticalruler-and-add-information)

[get line number within a eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980082/get-line-number-within-a-eclipse-plugin)